Why can't I create a sparse file in Windows 10 larger than 8TB?
I am using the information found here to create an empty sparse file on my NTFS partition in Windows 10. Online, if seen sources that claim Windows/NTFS supports files up to 256TB or 16EB, yet fsutil fails on anything over 8TB. I've also tried using powershell and FileStream.SetLength, so it's not simply a fsutil limitation.
